# Identify syntax region under cursor

Tags: vimscript

I'm writing a VimL function that needs to behave differently for different filetypes. I know I can use `&filetype` to detect that, but my issue is with files that have embedded languages. Let's say I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div {
      text-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the cursor is inside the style tag, I want to know that I'm dealing with CSS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name")` will return `css*` (like `cssStyle` or `cssDefinition`) inside the style tag.

Comment: If this is something you do often then [Tim Pope's scriptease.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin provides `zS` mapping. Poor man's mapping: `nnoremap zS :echo join(reverse(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val,"name")')),' ')<cr>`

Comment: seems to return blank for me.

Comment: @artfulrobot you need to have `ft` defined for it to work (for example in a syntax highlighted file)

Comment: yeah it is defined.