# How to get the highlight group of the word under the cursor in Neovim with Treesitter installed?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, highlight, highlighting

Ok folks, I've tried all these duplicates:

- [How to know which highlighting group is used for the background of a word?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/how-to-know-which-highlighting-group-is-used-for-the-background-of-a-word)
- [How to identify the highlight groups in use on a particular character?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/how-to-identify-the-highlight-groups-in-use-on-a-particular-character?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to check what of highlight is the word on cursor?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/how-to-check-what-of-highlight-is-the-word-on-cursor?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Identify syntax region under cursor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11871/identify-syntax-region-under-cursor)

But none of them work in for me in Neovim (0.8.2). And the plugin at https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax more helpfully reports "No syntax highlight groups under cursor".

I'm testing by putting my cursor in a word in a highlighted PHP doc and then firing the suggested command(s).

I just want my comments to be more readable (they're dark grey on black at the moment).

Is Neovim really different? Is it because I'm using Treesitter?

### EDIT

Running without any plugins, the above answers work, it seems to be treesitter that causes the problem.

A minimal config is

```lua
use {
'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter',
config = function()
  require('nvim-treesitter.configs').setup({
    highlight = { enable: true }
  })
  end,
}
```

Note that the problem only seems to occur when the treesitter's config specifies to enable `highlight`.

Comment: I suppose we will need a bit more information in order to reproduce the problem. Could you reproduce the problem on a minimal configuration (reduce at maximum the number of plugin that you install and limit the `vimrc` to the bare minimum). Let us know what you need to reproduce the problem. It will help us to reproduce and to help :-)

Comment: Along with minimal configuration, commands necessary after running `vim` to reproduce would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those using Neovim 0.9.0 (or newer), it now includes a command that does what you asked for (provided by a bundled runtime plugin):

```
:Inspect
```

Sources:

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.9.0

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/21393

Answer (score 10):

**Neovim v0.9**

The following commands are now available built-in, which do what you want

```
:Inspect             " prints as nicely formatted text
:Inspect!            " prints as a lua table
```

The lua API also has equivalent functions

```
vim.show_pos()       -- Similar to :Inspect (prints text)
vim.inspect_pos()    -- Similar to :Inspect! (returns table)
```

Beyond giving the highlight group for the cursor position, the output gives information on

- treesitter: a list of treesitter captures
- syntax: a list of syntax groups
- semantic_tokens: a list of semantic tokens
- extmarks: a list of extmarks

*See [:h lua-insector](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#lua-inspector)*

**Neovim v0.8** (original answer)

From ['nvim-treesitter/playground'](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/playground), there is the command

```
:TSHighlightCapturesUnderCursor
```

which does exactly this, presenting a nice popup at your cursor location.  It works similarly to

```
:TSNodeUnderCursor
```

to get the tree-sitter node at your cursor location.

Answer (score 2):

According to the closed issue at
https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/1654#issuecomment-893756730
Treesitter messes up  `synstack()`.

The only way to get a function to do something similar is through installing a 2nd plugin, [nvim-treesitter/playground](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/playground) and writing a lua function, like the one at
https://github.com/urbainvaes/vim-macaw/commit/be633f850fb54ed71cc6a1d46ee788380b7393b5

Manually, once you have playground installed you can start it up with `:TSPlaygroundToggle` then in the playground window press `i` to show highlight groups.